# Working With Encrypted Restful API in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I have a custom encryption algorithm that is used in my Node/Express API.

How can I ensure that the response is unencrypted by the time it reaches Postman?

Secondly, is there a way to test for this using Postman?

Comment: what backend technology do you use?

Comment: node js /express

Comment: The language in the original post was ambiguous. I have tried my best to keep the original spirit of the question